# If statement not giving proper result

Tags: javascript

```js
var bal = document.getElementById("o").value;
console.log(bal);

function a() {
  if (bal === "A") {
    console.log(ba);
    alert("Hello");

  } else {
    alert("jjhv");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="o">
    <input type="submit" id="oo" value="jhgf" onclick="a()">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

// here my aim is to alert the value "Hello" when user types "A" in the input field followed by click on input type submit.

But In the above code when user is giving input as anything ,and when user is submitting it the value assigned to variable "bal" becomes  empty string.

This is the reason for which only else block is being executed .I am unable to get the exact reason why this is happening .

Should I adopt any other approach to get the valid input field value ,so that I can successfully compare the value and alert the desired result

Comment: Move `var bal = document.getElementById("o").value;` inside the function `a()`

Comment: You're getting the value of your input before you typed into it.

Comment: You could also remove the `.value` from the `bal` var, and then do `bal.value` when you need it, this is because bal will be a reference to the DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function a(){
   var bal = document.getElementById("o").value;
   if(bal==="A"){
       console.log(bal);
       alert("Hello");
  }
 else{
     alert("jjhv");
     }   
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="o">
      <input type="submit" id="o" value="jhgf" onclick="a()">
    </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Here is a working code after correcting some errors in code

Comment: @CalvinNunes - Fixed them!